# What's wrong with this java Number list?

Tags: java, list, numbers

I have the following list. List is required by some other class i use.

```
List<Number> series, series2
```

series is full of 120 values, now I try to get every second value into series2 tha is empty

```
for (int num = 1; num < 121; num = num + 2) {
    series2.add(num, series.get(num));
}
```

Why does it crash?

Comment: It "crashes"? It's not Windows. Please also provide the stacktrace.

Comment: @amine OP is trying to get every *other* number, not every number.

Answer (score 5):

Without more code I can't say for sure, but it is most likely that you're never making `series2 = new LinkedList<Number>` or something similar.

Another problem I see is that you're starting at 1. The `List` interface implementations are typically 0 indexed, so you'd want

```
for(int num = 0; num < series.size(); num += 2)
```

Your best bet is to provide the entire code (what is necessary to compile and reproduce the problem) and the stack trace you're getting on the error as well.

EDIT:

It also depends on what you want for an output. Let's pretend your input in series is `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` and that we're dealing with only 10 numbers.

Would you want series 2 to be:

- `null,1,null,3,null,5,null,7,null,9`
- `1,null,3,null,5,null,7,null,9,null`
- `1,3,5,7,9`

If it's one of the first two, then you need to modify your loop to add the extra ones, like so:

```
for (int num = 0; num < 120; num++) {
    series2.add(num % 2 == 1 ? series.get(num) : null);
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
for(int num = 1; num < 120; num+=2) {
    series2.add(null);
    series2.add(series.get(num));
}
```

**In any event** attempting to add like this: `series2.add(num, series.get(num))` will probably fail. According to the documentation for `List.add(int,E)`

> Throws
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

So you can only use that to add to the middle of the `List`. If you want to add to the end, you have to use `List.add(E)`. If you want to add to some specific index in the `List` that it doesn't contain yet, you need to add `null`s (or something) until you get there. Obviously this is a problem if your `List` implementation doesn't support `null`s.

Comment: Clearly we need the OP's input here, but starting the index at 1 could very well be the intention.

Comment: @Rooke yes it does depend on what OP is trying to do, which isn't explicitly stated. I tried to cover the most likely case, but we'll see what OP says.

Comment: Starting at 1 was intentional as I wanted to have new list that contained what you described as option 3. New list containing 1,3,5,7,9.

Comment: @MaciejEckstein Then you're looking for `for(int num = 1; num < series.size(); num += 2)`

Answer (score 3):

You'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` thrown because you're adding things to series2 beyond the end of that list. Try just doing

```
series2.add(series.get(num));
```

Also, take glowcoder's advice and replace your loop bound by series.size(); however, your loop will not actually cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as it stands currently, since the last index that passes your conditional will be 119 - a valid index assuming 120 elements.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful if you told us the exception your getting.

From what you've told us though, I'd guess it's because series2 isn't initialised.

Answer (score 1):

Crashes how? It could be that you are referencing get(120) which doesn't exist. Elements would be number 0-119.